# How to avoid class tags override by methods tags with swagger?

Tags: java, swagger

Using Swagger 1.5.24, and following the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#api), i've wrote a swagger in this way:

```
@Path("/path1")
@Api(value = "Class for some requests", tags = {"Requests of type 1", "path1"})
public class Requests1 {

    @GET
    @Path("/request1")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Request 1 standard retriever", tags = {"standard", "version 1.0"})
    public Response getRequest1(..) { ... }

    @GET
    @Path("/request1/specific")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Request 1 specific retriever", tags = {"specific", "version 1.1"})
    public Response getRequest1specific(..) { ... }

    @POST
    @Path("/request1")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Request 1 standard inserter", tags = {"standard", "version 1.0"})
    public Response insertRequest1(..) { ... }

    @POST
    @Path("/request1/specific")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Request 1 specific inserter", tags = {"specific", "version 1.0"})
    public Response insertRequest1specific(..) { ... }

}
```

What i want to obtain is to list under the tags **Requests of type 1** and **path1** all the methods of the class, and to list under the tags **standard**, **version 1.0**, **specific** or **version 1.1** only the methods with tose tags specified.

Example:

**Request of type 1**

- Request 1 standard retriever
- Request 1 specific retriever
- Request 1 standard inserter
- Request 1 specific inserter
- ...

**Version 1.1**

- Request 1 specific retriever
- Request 2 standard inserter
- Request 5 ...

... and so on.

The problem is that settings the tags for the methods it overrides the tags of the class, resulting in an empty list for **Request of type 1** and **path1**.

I've tried to use the **@Tag** attribute inside the **@ApiOperation** attribute, but it show the folowing error:

> The value for annotation attribute ApiOperation.tags must be a constant expression

Answer (score 0):

I can "avoid" this problem setting the tags of the class for every methods, but doing so it will lower the readability of the specifics tags.

Example:

```
@Path("/path1")
@Api(value = "Class for some requests")
public class Requests1 {

    @GET
    @Path("/request1")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Request 1 standard retriever", tags = {"Requests of type 1", "path1", "standard", "version 1.0"})
    public Response getRequest1(..) { ... }
```